# jquery touch screen menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a parallax website and I have a menu on the top. The thing is, on touch screen devices when I click on a menu item it scroll to the page but when I scroll with my finger to another page the clicked button stay active!!

```
function redrawDotNav(){
    var section1Top =  0;
    // The top of each section is offset by half the distance to the previous section.
    var section2Top =  $('#Slide2').offset().top - (($('#Slide3').offset().top - $('#Slide2').offset().top) / 4);
    var section3Top =  $('#Slide3').offset().top - (($('#Slide4').offset().top - $('#Slide3').offset().top) / 2);
    var section4Top =  $('#Slide4').offset().top - (($('#Slide5').offset().top - $('#Slide4').offset().top) / 2);
    var section5Top =  $('#Slide5').offset().top - (($(document).height() - $('#Slide5').offset().top) / 2);;


    $('.link1').removeClass('active');
    $('.link2').removeClass('active');
    $('.link3').removeClass('active');
    $('.link4').removeClass('active');
    $('.link5').removeClass('active');

    $('.link1').removeClass('hover');
    $('.link2').removeClass('hover');
    $('.link3').removeClass('hover');
    $('.link4').removeClass('hover');
    $('.link5').removeClass('hover');


    if($('html').hasClass('no-touch')){

        if($(document).scrollTop() >= section1Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section2Top){
            $('.link1').addClass('active');

        } 
        else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section2Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section3Top){
            $('.link2').addClass('active');

        }

         else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section3Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section4Top){
            $('.link3').addClass('active');
        }

         else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section4Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section5Top){
            $('.link4').addClass('active');
        }

         else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section5Top){
            $('.link5').addClass('active');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic: Your first 10 statements could be one: `$('.link1, .link2, .link3, .link4, .link5').removeClass('hover active');` Better yet, classes should not be indexed so they apply to multiple elements. The rest could be combined with some minor refactoring.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no! the problem is that the touch event persist it get removed when i touch the screen again

Comment: How are you calling `redrawDotNav`?

Comment: i resolved the problem guys i've changed the menu :) thx